# How can I configure Playwright programmatically to take screenshots on failure?

Tags: cucumber, playwright, cucumberjs, playwright-test

I am using Cucumber integration with Playwright (e.g. https://github.com/e2e-boilerplate/playwright-commonjs-cucumber-expect/blob/master/features/support/steps.js). Because of this I don't have a playwright config file and I launch the browser manually

e.g.

```js
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ headless: true, u });
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await sharedContext.newPage();
```

However, I would like to configure Playwright to take a screenshot if a test fails (as described here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#automatic-screenshots).

Is this possible, or does use of Cucumber to run the tests mean this functionality becomes unavailable?

Comment: Did you try setting the flag `screenshot: 'only-on-failure',` in your `playwright.config.ts`?

Comment: Try using test.use, and set screenshot config. This is local per test configuration. Maybe you could combine it with fixtures for better coverage

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#local-configuration